# Where do I ask about an open-source telephony application for Android upon which I can build my project?

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation

I am currently working on a programming project and I have a question, but do not know where to ask it. I usually ask this stuff on Stack Overflow, but I think it would be off topic there: I am searching for an open-source telephony application for Android upon which I can build my project.

Can anybody tell me which site is the correct place for this question?

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for a specific piece of software, try [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com).

It was specifically created to give a place for people needing to find existing software - which is off-topic on Stack Overflow.

However, the bar is high there just like it is on SO: make sure your question complies with the rules in their [Help Center](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/asking).

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a go and take a look